# Word for person showing psychological projection

Tags: projection

Is there any single word for a person who shows more psychological projection (the defence mechanism of attribution of your own undesireable qualities to someone else) than a normal person? And is there a specific term for such condition?[Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection)
[everydayhealth.com](https://www.everydayhealth.com/emotional-health/psychological-projection-dealing-with-undesirable-emotions/)

Let me explain my question. A person showing extreme self importance is called a narcissist. So what do we call a person who shows extreme projections?

Answer (score -2):

Projection is both normal (we all do it always) and (in excess) a symptom of many different psychological disorders.

There is no name for such a person, as that symptom never occurs in isolation.

---

It is not correct that extreme self-importance makes someone a narcissist. Again, extreme self-importance can be found in many different disorders, and narcissism has many additional symptoms.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be backed up with reliable references so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's/answerer's background. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.